# Null pointer Exception when using view holder in list view adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I tried to implement view holder in my getView() method,however,it crashed and shows all those views in view holder is null,why,here is my code.

```
        if(view==null){
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_new_thing_item,null);
            viewHolder.progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_progress_bar);
            viewHolder.mainPictureImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_main_image);
            viewHolder.userIconImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_icon);
            viewHolder.thingsNameTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_name);
            viewHolder.priceTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_price);
            viewHolder.userNameTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_name);
            viewHolder.userCommentTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_comment);
            viewHolder. numberOfLikesTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_likes);
            viewHolder.numberOfAddToDouListTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_add_to_dou_list);
            viewHolder.numberOfReplyTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_reply);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }


        new DownloadItemImage().execute(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getMainPicture());
        new DownloadUserIcon().execute(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getUserIcon());
        viewHolder.thingsNameTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i - 1).getThingsName());
        viewHolder.priceTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getPrice());
        viewHolder.userNameTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getUserName());
        viewHolder.userCommentTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getUserComment());
        viewHolder.numberOfLikesTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getNumberOfLikes());
        viewHolder.numberOfAddToDouListTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getNumberOfAddToDouList());
        if(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getNumberOfReply().indexOf("评论")>=0){
            viewHolder.numberOfReplyTextView.setText(thingsItemArrayList.get(i-1).getNumberOfReply());
        }else{
            viewHolder.numberOfReplyTextView.setText("评论 0");
        }

        return view;
```

Comment: please show your Exception message, so we can help you. At least, it has a line where you can start with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `inflater.inflater()`, you didnt specify the parent view

Do this:

```
if(view==null){
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_new_thing_item,parent,false);
    viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
}else {
    viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
}
//Set values here.
//viewHolder.thingsNameTextView.setText(....);
//blah blah blah...
return view;
```

In viewHolder constructor:

```
public viewHolder(View view){
     viewHolder.progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_progress_bar);
        viewHolder.mainPictureImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_main_image);
        viewHolder.userIconImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_icon);
        viewHolder.thingsNameTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_name);
        viewHolder.priceTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_price);
        viewHolder.userNameTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_name);
        viewHolder.userCommentTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_comment);
        viewHolder. numberOfLikesTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_likes);
        viewHolder.numberOfAddToDouListTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_add_to_dou_list);
        viewHolder.numberOfReplyTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_reply);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
if(view == null){
...
}
```

do it like this.
if as you do,when view !=null,viewHolder equals null obviously.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way....

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             View view= convertView;
             ViewHolder viewHolder;

             if(convertView==null){

            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_new_thing_item,null);

            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_progress_bar);
            viewHolder.mainPictureImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_main_image);
            viewHolder.userIconImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_icon);
            viewHolder.thingsNameTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_name);
            viewHolder.priceTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_price);
            viewHolder.userNameTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_name);
            viewHolder.userCommentTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_user_comment);
            viewHolder. numberOfLikesTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_likes);
            viewHolder.numberOfAddToDouListTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_add_to_dou_list);
            viewHolder.numberOfReplyTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.find_new_thing_item_number_of_reply);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

         ........
         ..........

return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Null pointer Exception when using view holder in list view adapter

If you are using ButterKnife to bind the views and getting the Null Pointer Exception when holder try to access the views.

So, it might be Possible chances you have mistaken in build.gradle(app) file at the time of adding dependency/library of ButterKnife.

Please check again have you correctly added the Butterknife libaray and its annotateProcessor also with it.

Thanks
I hope this solution will help you.